# Yii2 - Search link in the gridview not working

Tags: yii2

In my yii2 project, I'm using Pjax GridView.

My `index` page:

```
<?= GridView::widget([
    'dataProvider' => $dataProvider,
    'filterModel' => $searchModel,
    'columns' => [
        ['class' => 'yii\grid\SerialColumn'],
        'id',
        'batch',
        [
             'attribute' => 'file_import',
             'format' => 'raw',
             'value'=>function ($data) {
                return Html::a($data->file_import, ['/device/index', 'DeviceSearch', 'batch' => $data->batch]);
            },
         ],

        ['class' => 'yii\grid\ActionColumn'],
    ],
]); ?>
```

The link in the `file_import` column goes to `http://localhost/index.php/device/index?1=DeviceSearch&batch=200325806610154437`. But in this url, all the data is showing instead of showing only the search result. I wanted to set the `file_import` column as an url which will show only the search result by the provided parameter in the url.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Are you sure that route in the link is ok?

Comment: Yes sir, I'm sure that route link is okay.

Comment: Well, if you say so... I would bet my money on `['/device/index', 'DeviceSearch[batch]' => $data->batch]` but it's your code.

Comment: Thank you for your solution. It is working. :)

Comment: No problems, I've added it as answer so you can accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change URL route to

```
['/device/index', 'DeviceSearch[batch]' => $data->batch]
```